# Show that the series $\sum 3^n \sin(\frac{1}{4^n} x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $(a,\infty)$, where $a>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that the series $\sum 3^n \sin(\frac{1}{4^n} x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $(a,\infty)$, where $a>0$.

I am unable to determine how to apply the *Weierstrass M-test* here. Please show me how should I decide $M_n$ s.t. $|f_n(x)|\le M_n$.

Comment: How can the $M$-test work?  $f_n(4^n)=3^n\sin1$

Comment: Are you sure you've written the series correctly? Maybe it's $\displaystyle\sum\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n\sin(4^nx)$?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x$ always less than $x$ for $x>0$
$\implies \sin(1/4^n x) < 1/4^n x$

$3^n \sin(1/4^nx) < (3/4)^n \cdot 1/x$

$\max{ (3/4)^n \cdot 1/x}  =  (3/4)^n \cdot 1/a$  which converges

Hence by Weierestrass theory the given series converges uniformly.

Answer (score -2):

You serie is differentiable

1. $|f_n(x)|\leq \dfrac{3^n}{4^n}x$ so it converges pointwise absolutely
2. $f_n$ is differentiable for all $n$
3. $|f_n|=\dfrac{3^n}{4^n}|\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{4^n}\right)|\leq\dfrac{3^n}{4^n}\triangleq M_n'$

$$ f'(x)=\sum \dfrac{3^n}{4^n}\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{4^n}\right)$$

By the derivation under sum sign theorem $f'$ exists and to answer your question

**$\sum f_n $is uniformaly convergent also.**

Note : I made a detour by the derivated serie to seek uniform convergence for the initial serie.